# "ant eclipse" not working for Apache Nutch repository

Tags: java, eclipse, nutch

I want to use Apache Nutch in Eclipse and I followed the steps from this site https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse, but when I run `ant eclipse`, it always restarts with the following lines at the beginning:

```
$ ant eclipse
Buildfile: /.../nutch/build.xml
Trying to override old definition of task javac
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/rat/anttasks/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

clean-build:
   [delete] Deleting directory /.../nutch/build

clean-default-lib:

clean-test-lib:

clean-lib:

clean-dist:

clean-eclipse:

ivy-probe-antlib:

ivy-download:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/rat/anttasks/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
```

I don't where the program should find the resource `org/apache/rat/anttasks/antlib.xml` because there is no `org` folder. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The warning about the missing "rat/anttasks/antlib.xml" can be ignored. It will disappear if the [Apache Rat](http://creadur.apache.org/rat/apache-rat-tasks/) jar is installed by executing `ant rat-sources` is executed. This task is only required for source code maintenance (it verifies whether LICENSE headers are attached to all source files).

The target `ant eclipse` is executed once and write the Eclipse project files (`.project` and `.classpath`) which allow to import the Nutch source tree as Eclipse project.

Comment: Fyi, you discovered a bug. Thanks! It's tracked on [NUTCH-2899](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-2899).